# How to append two block elements in to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I know `<p>` and `<h1>` are block elements but even with `display: inline-block;` nothing happens. H1 still overrides the P tag. What am I doing wrong? I've tried multiple methods, I'm sure it's really simple.

The code is below.

```
  let newContent = document.createElement('div');
    newContent.classList.add('new');
    let mewOne = document.createElement('h1'); 
    newContent.style.cssText = 'border-color: black; background-color:pink;';



 mewOne.textContent ="hey, i'm in a div";
    let mewTwo = document.createElement('p');
    mewTwo.textContent ="me too";
    container.appendChild(mewOne, mewTwo);

full code ------
Html 



 


JS 

    const container = document.querySelector('#container');
    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('content');
    content.textContent = 'My first dom manipulation!';
    container.appendChild(content);
    //first//
    
    
    let newContent = document.createElement('div');
    newContent.classList.add('new');
    let mewOne = document.createElement('h1'); 
    newContent.style.cssText = 'border-color: black; background-color:pink;';
    
    mewOne.textContent ="hey, i'm in a div";
    let mewTwo = document.createElement('p');
    mewTwo.textContent ="me too";
    container.appendChild(mewOne, mewTwo);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    //second//
    
    const contentHeading = document.createElement('h3');
    contentHeading.classList.add('new');
    contentHeading.textContent = "i'm blue h3!";
    contentHeading.style.color = 'blue';
    container.appendChild(contentHeading);
    //third///
    const contentParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    contentParagraph.classList.add('new');
    contentParagraph.textContent ="Hey i'm red";
    contentParagraph.style.color = 'red';
    container.appendChild(contentParagraph);
    //fourth//
```

Comment: You seem to be missing your HTML in your question

Comment: `container.appendChild(mewOne, mewTwo);` - in this line should be added only one element, not two. Just add `mewOne` and `mewTwo` in different lines.